# How to downgrade the kernel in Alpine Linux (in Docker)?

Tags: kernel, docker, alpine-linux

I'm looking to test a DirtyPipe PoC and I need a vulnerable kernel version (5.8-5.15) to test on. I'm running an Alpine container in Docker for this purpose however am open to other Linux distros (such as Debian) if it'll be easier to setup there. The only way I can come up with that would work for this purpose is personally compiling the kernel but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what a container is:

It's your Linux kernel giving a process (and all of its children) a different view on filesystem, users, network, IPC,…. But it's not a separate kernel!

So, your only choice  to run a different kernel is to boot into that kernel. Either physically booting a different Linux, or by booting in a VM. Of course, setting up a VM is much faster (especially in times of `vagrant`), but I'm not sure whether the nested page approach inherent to VMs would not make your DirtyPipe less likely to succeed.

Comment: Ah you're totally right. My mistake. Thank you.